# Close ssh session at the end of bash script

Tags: ssh, bash, shell-scripting

In the .profile of each user of the system (debian 8), I call a script who start a typescript session, to log everything in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash

script -f $HOME/.log/$(date +"%d-%b-%y_%H-%M-%S")_shell.log
```

The thing is when you enter "exit" then, you just stop the typscrit session, not the ssh connection, so you have to enter exit again. I would like to close ssh connection when we exit the typescript by enter "exit". I tried differents things:

At the end of my script:

```
exit
or
logout
or 
$(logout)
```

All of this return an error after exiting the typescript, for instance with `logout` or `$(logout)`:

```
/pathtoscript/log.sh: 9: /pathtoscript/log.sh: logout: not found
```

But it's a system command so I just need to execute this in system at the end of the script and that should be good!

in .bashrc:

```
function exit() { builtin exit && exit; }
```

Nothing append with this function, when I hit "exit" the typescript stop but not the ssh session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stuff doesn't work the way you want it, but exactly as you told it:

.profile is sourced by your shell, just as if you would have typed each character by hand. If you execute a script or other program in your shell, you expect to return to your prompt as soon as it has finished. This is exactly what you are experiencing.

You can put an exit into your .profile and it will exit as if you had typed it in an interactive shell. Your .profile might look like this then:

```
# ... whatever comes before
script -f $HOME/.log/$(date +"%d-%b-%y_%H-%M-%S")_shell.log
exit
```

Happy logging of your users!

Comment: Thank you it's working that way. This is usefull to check what are doing my students!

Comment: Using `exec script ...` should also work, since it replaces the shell with the `script` program (and thus there's no shell to exit at the end).